# How to prove that the distribution function $F_{X}(x)$ for a continuous random variable X is differentiable almost everywhere?

Tags: random-variables

Does anyone know about how to prove  the distribution function $F_{X}(x)$ for a continuous random variable X is differentiable almost everywhere?

Comment: You can find a proof of the latter part [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=YDkDmQ_hdmcC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA111&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @Hellen I don't think it needs to have a finite number of discontinuities (consider the CDF of any distribution with support just on all the integers). Countable though.

Comment: @Hellen still even though the countable part would save the first part of your argument I think it might wreck (or at least complicate) the second. For instance it's possible for a nondecreasing bounded function to be discontinuous on a countable dense set of points like the rationals. This is somewhat moot since OP asked specifically about continuous RVs to which the theorem about non-decreasing continuous functions can be applied directly